# Is there a better way or library to handle options menu in android actionbar/toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I have an `OptionsMenu` which will contain only two items settings and logout.
To implement it, I'm repeating the same code in each activity. i.e., implementing `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods in each activity.

Is there a better way to do this? I can see that it's just repeating the same code over and over. If I have ten activities, I'm doing it in ten.

Please suggest some better way to do this. Is there a way to implement it in single place etc.

I hope I'm making some sense.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no library to the best of my knowledge - asking for library recommendations is a certain way to get your question voted for close (this is not allowed on SO).

Comment: Use a BaseActivity where you can implement these methods for all sub Activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good OO practise if you extend the Android Activity class with your default menu requirements. Like so:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class OptionsMenuActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Settings");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Logout");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0: // Settings
                // Do your funky stuff
                break;
            case 1: // Logout
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now all your activity classes which extend from OptionsMenuActivity will have this menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new utility class (*MenuHelper.java*) to handle this.  In it you can have a method that instantiates your menu.

Then in that class just have a method to setup your menu (setupMenu(Context cxt, Menu menu) - you will just have to pass the proper objects to the method like Activity Context, and Menu - (perhaps something like this: *setupMenu(Context cxt, Menu menu)* ).

Comment: I used your suggesstion, kept onCreateOptionsMenu as earlier but reduced onOptionItemSelected using 
`@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        MenuHelper.setupMenu(MainActivity.this, item);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a better way. Create a class for templating event handlers. Maybe you can name it `EventTemplate`. There you can implement the event handlers you want. Use the corresponding event handler template function for each event. So, instead of duplicating your code ten times, you can implement it once and use it whenever you need it.

Comment: Down-voter, can you explain why do you believe this post is not helpful?